# vmware Deploying OVA through python api

Tags: python, ssl, vmware, vcenter, pyvmomi

Running into some challenges with deploying an OVA.  Been beating my head against the wall for a couple days and need to call in some help.

The goal is to deploy an OVA to a vcenter.  Keep in mind this is a lab environment so there are self signed certs.   Ideally i would like to create a flag that i can toggle depending on the environment its run in.

The script runs and connects - however when it goes to upload it looks like it wants to upload however it just times out and cancels itself.

The error that my script outputs is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/nestedlabs/test_combine.py", line 105, in <module>
    deploy_ova(si, ova_url, cluster_name, datastore_name, vm_name, vm_config)
  File "/workspaces/nestedlabs/test_combine.py", line 71, in deploy_ova
    session.put(url, data=file, timeout=7)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 649, in put
    return self.request("PUT", url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.10.100.10', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /nfc/520bbbb4-6b20-d263-041d-6492c679159a/disk-0.vmdk (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)')))
```

The script i have so far is the following. The ips and passwords have been changed - they are bogus for this post.

```
from pyVmomi import vim
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
import ssl
import requests
import tempfile
import shutil
import tarfile
import os
import time

class WebHandle(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            raise FileNotFoundError(url)
        self.file_handle = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.ova', delete=False)
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, self.file_handle)
        self.file_handle.flush()
        self.file_handle.seek(0)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.file_handle

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.file_handle.close()
        os.unlink(self.file_handle.name)

def deploy_ova(si, ova_url, cluster_name, datastore_name, vm_name, vm_config):
    with WebHandle(ova_url) as ova_file:
        tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=ova_file)
        ovf_file = [f for f in tar.getnames() if f.endswith('.ovf')][0]
        ovf_descriptor = tar.extractfile(ovf_file).read().decode()

        content = si.RetrieveContent()
        cluster = next((c for c in content.rootFolder.childEntity[0].hostFolder.childEntity if c.name == cluster_name), None)
        resource_pool = cluster.resourcePool if cluster else content.rootFolder.childEntity[0].host[0].parent.resourcePool
        datastore = next((ds for ds in (cluster.datastore if cluster else content.rootFolder.childEntity[0].host[0].datastore) if ds.name == datastore_name), None)
        vm_folder = content.rootFolder.childEntity[0].vmFolder

# Create the customization properties
        property_mappings = [
            vim.KeyValue(key='guestinfo.hostname', value=vm_config['hostname']),
            vim.KeyValue(key='guestinfo.ipaddress', value=vm_config['ipaddress']),
            vim.KeyValue(key='guestinfo.netmask', value=vm_config['netmask']),
            vim.KeyValue(key='guestinfo.gateway', value=vm_config['gateway']),
            vim.KeyValue(key='guestinfo.dns', value=vm_config['dns']),
            vim.KeyValue(key='guestinfo.ntp', value=vm_config['ntp']),
            # vim.KeyValue(key='guestinfo.ssh', value='true'),
            vim.KeyValue(key='guestinfo.password', value=vm_config['password']),
            # Add other properties here...
        ]
        spec_params = vim.OvfManager.CreateImportSpecParams(entityName=vm_name, propertyMapping=property_mappings)
        manager = content.ovfManager
        import_spec = manager.CreateImportSpec(ovf_descriptor, resource_pool, datastore, spec_params)
        lease = resource_pool.ImportVApp(import_spec.importSpec, vm_folder)

        while lease.state == vim.HttpNfcLease.State.initializing:
            time.sleep(1)

        if lease.state == vim.HttpNfcLease.State.error:
            print("Lease error: ", lease.error)
            return
        session = requests.Session()
        session.verify = False

        for device_url in lease.info.deviceUrl:
            file_path = next((f for f in import_spec.fileItem if f.deviceId == device_url.importKey), None).path
            file = tar.extractfile(file_path)
            url = device_url.url.replace('*', '10.10.100.12') # Replace with the correct IP
            session.put(url, data=file, timeout=7)

        lease.HttpNfcLeaseComplete()

        vm = lease.info.entity
        task = vm.PowerOn()
        while task.info.state == vim.TaskInfo.State.running:
            time.sleep(1)

        print(f"Deployed {vm_name} successfully!")
# Connect to the vCenter server
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
ssl_context.check_hostname = False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

si = SmartConnect(host="10.10.100.12", user="administrator@vsphere.local", pwd="Password1234", sslContext=ssl_context)

# Deploy the OVA
ova_url = 'https://10.10.100.147/public-archives/download/Test/Nested_ESXi6.5u3_Appliance_Template_v1.ova'
cluster_name = 'Test1'
datastore_name = 'datastore1'
vm_name = 'YourVM'
vm_config = {
    'hostname': 'your-hostname',
    'ipaddress': '10.100.100.240',
    'netmask': '255.255.255.0',
    'gateway': '10.100.100.1',
    'dns': '10.100.100.111',
    'ntp': '4.2.2.2',
    # 'ssh': 'True',
    'syslog': '10.100.100.111',
    'password': 'WhatAPassWord!!',
    # Add other properties here...
}
deploy_ova(si, ova_url, cluster_name, datastore_name, vm_name, vm_config)

# Disconnect from the vCenter server
Disconnect(si)
```